# Streaming to write Json

Tags: java, json, io, stream, gson

I have a large set of `JsonObject`s inside a `ArrayList`. I need to add these `JsonObject`s into a `JsonArray` and write it into a file. I am using `Gson` and below is my code.

```
private void myWriter(List<JsonObject> jsonObjectHolder, int number) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Starting to write the JSON File");
        //Add everything into a JSONArray
        JsonArray jsonArrayNew = new JsonArray();

        for(int i=0;i<jsonObjectHolder.size();i++)
        {
            //System.out.println("inside array: "+i);
            JsonObject o = jsonObjectHolder.get(i);
            System.out.println("inside array "+i+": "+o.get("title"));

            jsonArrayNew.add(jsonObjectHolder.get(i));
        }

        System.out.println("Size: "+jsonArrayNew.size());

        //Write it to the File
        File file= new File("items.json");

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);;
        fw.write(jsonArrayNew.toString());
        fw.flush();
        fw.close();

        System.out.println("outside array");


    }
```

I don't like this way. The `ArrayList` holds lot of data and the way I write could generate `OutOfMemoryError`. Instead, I would like to Stream and write these to the file.

**Update**

According to the answer of SO user "Alden", here how I edited the code.

```
private void myWriter(List<JsonObject> jsonObjectHolder) throws IOException
{
    JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new FileWriter(new File("items.json")));
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    writer.beginArray();

    for (JsonObject jsonObject : jsonObjectHolder)
    {
        gson.toJson(jsonObject, writer);
    }

    writer.endArray();

    writer.close();
}
```

Please let me know whether this is the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Gson to stream your list like this:

```
private void myWriter(List<JsonObject> jsonObjectHolder, Gson gson) throws IOException
{
    JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new FileWriter(new File("items.json")));

    writer.beginArray();

    for (JsonObject jsonObject : jsonObjectHolder)
    {
        gson.toJson(jsonObject, writer);
    }

    writer.endArray();

    writer.close();
}
```

This assumes you have a `Gson` instance that you can use. If you do not, you can use `writer.beginObject()` with `writer.endObject()` and manually add properties to the writer, but I wouldn't recommend this because you've already done the work of building a `JsonObject`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Gson object means, just simply this? `Gson g = new Gson()`. I can simply create this instance inside the method right?

Comment: Yes you can. You might want that to be created elsewhere if you need [custom serializers](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization), but you shouldn't here because you're dealing with `JsonObject`, so inline is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I made an update to my post, including your answer. Please have a look.

Comment: Ok is there something wrong with my answer? Or is there something else you are looking for? It seems like this solves your problem

Comment: i think he did not want to make the full object and then write it, instead write it as its being collected (from db or elsewhere) so write each row as it is produced. that way do not need to write to a in memory array. Direct to output stream. Your post helps in that.