# JSONObject.toString() is creating OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, json, xml, out-of-memory

I have to convert StackExchange's dataset to Json file, so I have tried this-

```
public class Parser {
    public static int PRETTY_FACTOR=4;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  
        String fileName = "/home/dipannoy/Desktop/stackexchange/android/posthistory.json";
        String path= "/home/dipannoy/Desktop/stackexchange/android/PostHistory.xml";

        try {           

            StringBuilder builder =  new StringBuilder();  


            FileInputStream inputStream = null;
            Scanner sc = null;
            try {
                inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
                sc = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
                while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line = sc.nextLine();
                    builder.append(line);
                }
                if (sc.ioException() != null) {
                    throw sc.ioException();
                }
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
                if (sc != null) {
                    sc.close();
                }
            }


            String xml  = builder.toString();  
            JSONObject jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(xml);   


            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter =new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

            bufferedWriter.write(jsonObj.toString());
            bufferedWriter.flush();            
            bufferedWriter.close();
            fileWriter.close();
        }


          catch(IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(
                    "Error writing to file '"
                    + fileName + "'");

            } catch(Exception e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }
    }  
}
```

But it was having error at `jsonObj.toString()` .
A sample xml is -

```
<comments>
<row Id="1" PostId="1" Score="4" Text="Did I just place the first upvote?  Congrats on getting this site off the ground!" CreationDate="2016-01-12T18:47:12.573" UserId="23"/>
</comments>
```

I have tried to use Gson but failed to convert `GSONObject` to `GsonObject` as `GsonParser` need to have `GSONObject`'s `toString()` method which is creating the `OutOfMemoryError`. Can anyone help in this matter?

Comment: Do you understand that you're loading the whole dataset in memory, and thus the `OutOfMemoryError`? Other than writing the code for you, I'm not sure what anyone can do to help. Look up StAX parser.

Comment: If it *just* fails on the JSONObject.toString (the XML and the JSON Object graph is *already* entirely loaded in memory, etc), it should be possible to use a *streaming writer* - ref. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577848/streaming-to-write-json A streaming writer will *not* invoke to-string first, as that would, well, defeat the purpose of streaming. Even if (Gson's implementation) can't be used directly from JSONObject, it should be possible to traverse sections of the object graph and emit those separately though the streaming writer. Of course, streaming from end-to-end..

Answer (score 0):

There is an [underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library with static method `U.xmlToJson(xml)`. I am the maintainer of the project.

```
<comments>
<row Id="1" PostId="1" Score="4" Text="Did I just place the first upvote?  Congrats on getting this site off the ground!" CreationDate="2016-01-12T18:47:12.573" UserId="23"/>
</comments>
```

Output:

```
{
  "comments": {
    "row": {
      "-Id": "1",
      "-PostId": "1",
      "-Score": "4",
      "-Text": "Did I just place the first upvote?  Congrats on getting this site off the ground!",
      "-CreationDate": "2016-01-12T18:47:12.573",
      "-UserId": "23",
      "-self-closing": "true"
    }
  },
  "#omit-xml-declaration": "yes"
}
```